# Duplicated content on google. htaccess or robots.txt?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, robots.txt, canonical-link

In my website I have the following categories url structure:

`/category.php?id=6` (id=6 is for internet category)

My SEO friendly url is like:

```
/category/6/internet/
```

The problem is it can be accessed in any of those forms, and because of that, I'm getting duplicate content on google.

So, I'm wondering how can I fix that.

Should I disallow on `robots.txt` any urls with `?` on it?

If so, how can I properly set it up?

Should I make a redirection "Permanently Moved" on `.htaccess`?

If so, how can I properly set it up?

My actual `.htaccess` for categories is like this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ category.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have you chosen `/category/6/internet/` as your SEO-friendly URL instead of `/category/internet/`?

Comment: @msanford Probably because he needs the category id without having to do a lookup based on name.

Comment: @OmarJackman I agree, but it should be possible to do the latter, especially in light of SEO? Perhaps it doesn't matter.

Comment: @msanford, im using a pre-made script as base, and this script im using as base works that way. Im am trying to figure out how can i remove this id from urls... My posts urls are like `siteurl.com/12/slug-post-title/` and im working on how to remove the ids from url. If you have any idea...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the canonical link tag in the head section of your pages

see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

and http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

It will look something like

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/category/6/internet/"/>
```

on the category 6 page

You could also do a 301 redirect for the category.php pages in your .htaccess by adding

```
RewriteRule ^category.php?id=([^&]*)&name=([^&]*) /category/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

If you didn't want to go the route of rewriterules you could put the following code at the top of config.php:

```
if(preg_match('/^\/config\.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: /category/{$_GET['id']}/{$_GET['name']}");
    die();
}
```

Either way is up to you but I would use the rewriterule option to redirect to my SEO friendly URL If I were you

Comment: The rewriterule option gets a little tricky with preserving querystring variables but its still a good solution that can be refined

Comment: whats the difference between your rewrite rule and mine? i need to replace mine with yours?

Comment: No, you don't replace your rule. You add my rule and also keep yours. The difference is that if a person hits category.php?blablah it will do a 301 redirect to the seo friendly url. The rule you currently have is not a redirect, its just a rewrite.

Comment: OK i got it. At James Pegg answer he says that using canonical urls is better than using htaccess redirections, do you think the same way?

Comment: I cant say which is better, its a matter of preference in my opinion. The rewriterule will keep people from seeing your ugly urls if they come across it. It will also keep people from sharing your ugly urls.

Comment: This RewriteRule is not working. It is not redirecting. WHen i go to `siteurl/category.php?id=6&name=internet` it loads the page and dont redirect me to `siteurl/6/internet/` Whats wrong pls?

Answer (score 1):

Or you get rid of the non-SEO url.

- always generate SEO url (you should do that anyway for)
- in category.php check if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is the seo one and if not redirect to it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a canonical link in the document head to ensure Google uses the correct URL. [Google on Rel Canonical](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394).

It's really easy to implement, just post this into the HEAD section of the page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/your/url"/>
```

Google treats the canonical link as a 301 redirect, which means you won't have any duplicate content issues. It also means most of the link juice gets passed on (between 90% and 99%). If you used robots.txt or .htaccess , the page that you're blocking off would lose all its SEO value.

Just make sure you do this for every page as it's a page specific rule. Linking to the domain root will effectively mean all your pages are 301 redirecting to the home page.

Comment: you mean using canonical links will always be better than using htaccess or robotx.txt?

Comment: can i use both solutions? the canonial link and htaccess redirection?