# RewriteRule 301 redirect for urls with multiple query strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have urls like:

```
siteurl.com/category.php?id=6&name=internet
```

i want to make a 301 redirection to

```
siteurl.com/category/6/internet/
```

I tried without success:

```
RewriteRule ^category.php?id=([^&]*)&name=([^&]*) /category/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

More info about it: [Duplicated content on google. htaccess or robots.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827183/duplicated-content-on-google-htaccess-or-robots-txt)

Any help?

---

**Xtra Edit;** the page is also accessible via `siteurl.com/category.php?id=6` (witohut the name query). Whats the best way to deal with that? Redirect this kind of URL to the home page? If so, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The query string won't appear in the `RewriteRule` expression. Instead, you have to match it in a `RewriteCond`, via `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Capture the id and name into %1 and %2 from the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&name=([a-zA-Z-]+)
# If the query string does not include noredirect=
# This protects against a rewrite loop when attempting to 301 redirect the ugly URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !noredirect=
# Rewrite category.php to /category/id/name
RewriteRule ^category\.php /category/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

The `?`  is neccessary to avoid reapeating the queries at the end of URL.

```
# I assume you also have the following rule, which configures the pretty URL in the first place
# Then in the rule which points the pretty URL to the real internal one, add
# the fake query string param noredirect=1, which won't actually be used by PHP. It just 
# matches in the rules above to prevent rewriting when present
RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)/([^/]+) category.php?id=$1&name=$2&noredirect=1 [L]
```

Comment: its redirecting to the correct url now, but the page is not showing, its giving an error "Incorrect Redirection." on firefox.

Comment: @LucasMatos You are probably getting a redirection loop, if you also have a rule which points to the actual URL (the one you're trying to avoid) to process the script.  I'll post a trick above.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you did it. Just one xtra question: The URL is also accessible via `siteurl/category.php?id=6` (witohut the name query). I dont think its possible to make the same kind of redirection with just one query, right? So how can i redirect this kind of URL to the home page?

Comment: Just figured out that RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&name=([a-zA-Z]+) is avoiding the minus - in URLs. I think that is something missing here &name=([a-zA-Z]+) I have some URLs name queries like home-and-garden and your rewrite is getting only siteurl.com/category/3/home/ instead of siteurl.com/category/3/home-and-garden/ any clues?

Comment: btw, my rewrite rule for ugly urls is like `'RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ category.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]`

Comment: @LucasMatos If you have hyphens in the `name`, use `([A-Za-z-]+)`.